# sort a TreeSet with HashMap<string,integer> as its type

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, tree

For example,

```
TreeSet<HashMap<String,Integer>> myTree = new  TreeSet<HashMap<String,Integer>>();
```

I want to sort this treeset based on the Integer value from HashMap. Are there any good ways we could do this?

Comment: Provide a custom `Comparator<HashMap<String, Integer>>` on the constructor of `TreeSet`. Still, this seems like an odd design.

Comment: **The** integer value? Why do you use a Map to store one key and one value? You should create a class containing a String field and an Integer field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to design a custom comparator and provide it to your `TreeSet` as a constructor,

```
public static Set<HashMap<String, Integer>> myTree = new TreeSet<>(
                new Comparator<HashMap<String, Integer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(HashMap<String, Integer> o1,
                            HashMap<String, Integer> o2) {
                        return (o2.get(key)).compareTo(o1.get(key));
        }
});
```

just replace `key` with your integer's key.

If you want it to sort the other way around then,

replace,

```
o2.get(key)).compareTo(o1.get(key)
```

with,

```
o1.get(key)).compareTo(o2.get(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

As written ("sort this treeset based on the Integer value from HashMap"), this requirement either doesn't make sense, or refers to a complicated/confusing design.

Do you really want to order a collection of Maps based on their value sets? Or are you actually just using Map as a stand-in for, e.g., Tuple2?

If your intent is the former, then sure, you can create a customer Comparator; but the semantics of that Comparator will be non-obvious to most people, and you will likely end up with an implementation that exhibits O(n^2)-ish behavior on insertions/deletions.

And if it's the latter, then your system will once again be confusing, but its invariants will be even more poorly-modeled. That is, you are *assuming* that each Map contains exactly one key-value binding, and while you could certainly enforce this constraint with runtime checks, document it in javadoc, etc, it is a counterintuitive usage of the Map type. In this case, it would be much better, as  JB Nizet mentioned, to just create a container class with a String and Integer field, and you can easily sort collections of this class either by using a Comparator, or by making the class implement Comparable.